# Multi PDFs Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am using Prawn to genereate Pdfs for my application. On a page, I want to create two DIFFERENT pdfs with different information.

I have created two different pdfs in the show method under my `pdforms_controller`

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = MemberPdf.new(@pdform)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: 'Pdform.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
      end
      format.pdf do
        req = RequisitionPdf.new(@pdform)
        send_data req.render, filename: 'Requisition.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
      end
    end
  end
```

At the bottom of the Pdform show page I have two links, each linking to a different Pdf.

```
<%= link_to "View PDF", pdform_path(format: 'pdf'), class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
<%= link_to "View Requisition", pdform_path(format: 'pdf'), class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

They each have their own class, very similar to the other. I will just post one to save space in the post.

```
class RequisitionPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize
    super()
    text "Hello req form"
  end
end
```

When I click the first link, the View PDF link, it shows the same thing. For whatever reason is it not showing the Req pdf but rather the Pdform pdf. Any ideas why?

Comment: because both links link to the same target and you cannot `respond_to` two different `format.pdf`. How should your app know when to do which?

Comment: So is what I want to do possible? I'm not sure how I would differentiate the two.